# Timezone confusion with getRawOffset method

Tags: java, date, datetime

One of my project implemented the below method, i am looking into the one of the date issue and trying to understand below method which converts given date to GMT, but confused with the output.

Input Date value : 2010-11-29 04:00:00.0
Output Date value : Sun Nov 28 20:00:00 PST 2010

My machine is running in pacific timezone(PST), if it is returning GMT, i would expect "2010-11-29 11:00:00.0", can you please clarify what is the purpose of getRawOffset() method and why it is returning that output?

```
public static Date convertToGMT(Date date) {
    TimeZone jvmTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    long newTime = date.getTime() + jvmTimeZone.getRawOffset();

    if (jvmTimeZone.inDaylightTime(date)) {
        newTime = newTime + jvmTimeZone.getDSTSavings();
    }
    return new Date(newTime);
}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, avoid the TimeZone library, it's awful. Use Joda Time instead

Comment: My recommendation don't try to understand this code. You should rather try to get to know what was the intention or the goal and then code it new from the scratch. That is easier.

Answer (score 1):

PST is UTC-8, therefore `getRawOffset()` returns a negative value:

```
2010-11-29 04:00:00.0 + (-8 hours) = 2010-11-28 20:00:00.0
```

However, the whole thing you are trying to do is wrong.

`Date` represents an *instant*, a point on the timeline that's not associated with any timezone. Therefore it makes no sense to convert `Date` from one timezone to another. The only thing you can do with `Date` is to convert it to local date/time in certain timezone, and vice versa.

Also I'd suggest you to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) too. Jode Time makes distinction between an instant (`DateTime`) and a local representation of that instant (`LocalDateTime`) more clear.

Answer (score -1):

The code is just crap because a `java.util.Date` is always GMT. It is never a local timestamp so trying to convert it from an imaginary local timestamp to GMT is conceptual nonsense.

The original intention was probably to misuse a `Date` as a kind of local timestamp (in contradiction to its specification) that is as thin wrapper around local time millis. Remember following relation: [UTC-millis] + [offset-millis] = [local-millis] I would just have used a `long` primitive for this calculation, not j.u.Date.

So you can see many inconsistencies in the code. The `newTime` variable appears to be a kind of local millis but is wrapped then as j.u.Date and returned result of a method which pretends to convert to GMT (more chaos is hardly possible).

**Edit 8 years later when we have now got the `java.time`-package.**

An instance of `java.util.Date` can be converted to a `java.time.Instant`. New conversion methods had been added to `java.util.Date` for this purpose. And we should all know that an instant is related to GMT, and nothing else. So will someone try to tell us that following code makes any sense?

```
public static Instant convertToGMTNew(Instant instant) {
  java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from(instant);
  return convertToGMTOld(date).toInstant(); // using the method above
}
```

Not really. It is the same error. The new changed!!! instant would indeed be based on a fake calculation. `Instant` and `java.util.Date` have no conversion methods involving any zone calculations for a good reason. Both are just related to GMT and not to any "local" instants.